# Attempt to assign property of non-object warning, problem with var

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, get

So, I'm currently trying to get data from JavaScript and then write it into my Database with PHP.
My code looks like the following:

```
      $score_stacker = $request->post('score_stacker');
      $username_stacker = $request->post('username_stacker');
      $score = $request->get('score_stacker');
      $username = $request->get('username_stacker');

      settype($score, "integer");
      settype($susername, "string");

      $score->score_stacker = $score_stacker;
      $score_stacker->save();

      $username->username_stacker = $username_stacker;
      $username_stacker->save();

      return response()->json('new Highscore');
```

So when I try to post the values I get from the request, I get the error message: "Attempt to assign property 'score_stacker' of non-object"
Why cant I assign the values from the variable to the other ones?
Even though when I try a SQL create it doesnt work

```
$new_score = Highscore::create(['username_stacker' => $username, 'score_stacker' => $score]);
```

So theres probably something wrong with my var but what? When I dump it I get the correct values

Comment: You're trying to use $score var as an object, but it isn't an object, it's initialized as what is sent $request->get('score_stacker'); the same happens with $score_tracker, $username_stacker and $username variables, you're using them as objects. Do you really know what are you doing?

Comment: As you may noticed I'm probably not the best programmer, but I'm trying my best to get this done. I just dont really get how to post the values to the database so I try my best but I'm just stuck here..

Comment: Ok, first at all, refer to a manual and try to learn and get acknowledgement enough to do what you want. Having a certain knowledge basis, you can ask here whenever you find an unexpected trouble doing something, but not a void on how to do something. About your post, the error is clear: using a variable as an object, but it isn't and object. But there isn't information enough in your exposition to know what are you exactly doing. However, if you're expecting to pass an object by post or get "as it", you're totally wrong. You need to learn more, don't get me wrong, that's my recomendation.